# how I can do on release input if empty fill with value using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have this input field is given below. when we click on the input field it clear field but 1 issue if the user does not enter any value it remains empty I want on release empty input it refills with old input value `value="{{ $p->price }}"` how I can do that?

```
<input style="width: 70px;" onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="{{ $p->price }}" class="form-control" {{ Auth::user()->role < 3 ? '' : 'readonly' }} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two similar methods - one inline and the other as external event handlers. The basic gist is to capture a reference to the original value and store in a variable, reassign this value when the element loses focus if nothing has been entered into the field

```js
var value;
var input=document.querySelector('input[name="bob"]');

input.onfocus=function(e){
  value=this.value;
  this.value='';
}
input.onblur=function(){
  if( this.value=='' )this.value=value;
}
```

```html
<input name='boo' type="text" value="apple" class="form-control" onfocus='tmp=this.value;this.value=""' onblur='if(this.value=="")this.value=tmp' />
<input name='bob' type="text" value="banana" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an onfocus which will save the value, and then an onblur which will restore the old value if the new is ''.

```
<input onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value" value="abc" onblur="this.value = this.value || this.oldvalue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding something of the form
... `onblur="this.value=\"The value you want\""` ...
in your input field? The blur event is basically the "defocus" event so to speak.